# php "preg_match" function syntax to select images ordered in slideshow by number

Tags: php, syntax, preg-match

I need to verify the proper syntax after the "`preg_match`" function that will select slide images that are ordered in a slideshow initially by number.  The following is the code in my "php" file the selects the files to be fed to javascript/jquery for the slideshow.

```
$photovar=$_GET['id']; 
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]+$/i', $photovar)){ 
    echo 'alert("Photo Album ID must contain only letters, numbers, or underscore, and cannot start with a number")'; 
    die(); 
}
```

I think I can remove "`^[a-z_] [a-z0-9_]`" and replace with "`[^A-Z]`" to select everything but capital letters.  However, I don't know what to do with the "echo" construct. I think I can remove everything from the brace to brace without any problem but not certain.  I understand the "`die()`" construct is not well liked anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is not working? What is the input string sample and the expected result?

Comment: Above from javascriptkit.com.  8th slide program in the list. Uses php to send list of images from directory to a javascript/jquery routine.  Web host upgraded  to php 7 & slideshow no longer functions.  php file had deprecated code (regedi).  Update php file with preg-match will not upload slides because it will not load images that start with numbers.  All images in my directories ordered by 3 digit number.  I am trying to fix the updated "php" file to collect images that start with numbers.

Comment: Please post the whole relevant code in the question, add some sample string you want to match and some that should not, or just provide the expected output.